# como obtener el indice de un elemento en un array de arrays

Tags: java, array

Tengo una matriz y necesito encontrar el indice de un elemento especifico en una **columna**.

He visto el metodo index of pero solo usado en arreglos normales de strings, ints etc no en arreglos de arreglos o matrices.

por ejemplo tengo `String tablero[][]= new String[15][35];`

y quiero hacer algo como

`tablero.indexOf(tablero[columna], "*");// claramente esto no funciona`

```
int indice=tablero[columna].indexOf("*")// esto tampoco
```

lo estoy tratando de hacer siguiendo este ejemplo

```
import java.io.*;
public class Test {

public static void main(String args[]) {
    String Str = new String("Welcome to Tutorialspoint.com");
    System.out.print("Found Index :" );
    System.out.println(Str.indexOf( 'o' ));
 }
}
```

Comment: `Arrays.asList(tablero[columna]).indexOf("*")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Teniendo una matriz 3 x 3 como ejemplo

```
String arreglo[][] = new Int[3][3];
```

si en las casillas [2][1] tenemos como valor un "*", lo recomendable es buscar por un ciclo for anidado

```
for(int fila = 0; fila < arreglo.length; fila++)
   for(int columna = 0; columna < arreglo[fila].length; columna++)
      if(arreglo[fila][columna]).equals("*")
         System.out.printf("El asterisco esta en las casillas [%d][%d]", 
                            fila, columna );
```

Comment: en las dos ultimas lineas de tu respuesta, que hace diferente printf de println? y [%d] de alguna manera se rellena con el numero de fila o columna?. aparte de eso me quedo todo muy claro. gracias!

Comment: @zedsdeath, printf ayuda a imprimir una linea con formato, vemos que hay dos "%d", significa que estableceras dos valores enteros, por ello incorpore las variables fila y columna, ambos son enteros y sustituirian los dos simbolos de %d por sus valores, saludos

Answer (score 1):

lo más sencillo de realizar sería utilizar 2 for loops anidados (uno para recorrer las filas y otro para las columnas).

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("A encontrar: ");
String elemento = sc.nextLine();

for(int i=0;i<filas;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<columnas;j++){
        if(tablero[i][j].equals(elemento)){
            System.out.println("Elemento encontrado en fila " + i +" columna " + j);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

También sería conveniente guardar la cantidad de filas y columnas en variables para utilizarlas al momento de crear la matriz.

```
int filas = 15;
int columnas = 35;

String tablero[][]= new String[filas][columnas];
```

Comment: Gracias! coincides con @Abraham Araujo Moreno,con la respuesta de arriba pero al final como Dev. Joel fue el primero en contestar termine utilizando su sugerencia